# Missing valid API Key Google Sheet Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google Sheet called StockHistory and Sheet called Test all under Spreadsheet called Investment.

I'm trying to use Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get() in Apps Script to read data from StockHistory that is in the same container of the Apps Script which is Investment. in the Execution Log I can read the data just fine. However, when I call the function in the Test Sheet, I receive Missing valid API Key.

How to solve this as I'm trying to read from one sheet and place the result into another sheet after applying some logic to the data?

```
async function AVGCOST(stockCode) {
 
  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SpreadsheetID','StockHistory!A:E').values;
  /*
  somelogic
  */
  return range;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Hi, first let me recommend you to use [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) if you are doing simple tasks and don't need specific functions. Otherwise, you can use [Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), as you are doing, which facilitates the use of different APIs like [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) and can perform some extra functions. To use them you need to [activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) them first.

Furthermore, having done some research, I see that this is a common problem what you are experiencing. It is not that easy to use the `Sheets API` in a custom function in `Google Sheets`, although it is possible if needed. So, I recommend you use `Spreadsheet Service`, I've attached the code in both versions so you can try it out.

### Sheets API

```
function test() {
  var range = 'Sheet2!A1:A5'
  var SpreadsheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SpreadsheetID,range).values;
  return values
}
```

### Spreadsheet Service

```
function test() {
  var range = 'Sheet2!A1:A5'
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var values = sheet.getRange(range).getValues()
  return values
}
```

### update

[Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) can open inactive Spreadsheets and Sheets. There are several options:

- **Spreadsheets:**

  - [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) open a Spreadsheet document with its id
  - [openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)) open a Spreadsheet document with its url
- **Sheets:**

  - [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) get a Sheet from a document with its name
  - [getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) get all the sheets from a document in an array
  - Example

    ```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var test = ss.getSheetByName('test')
    var stock = ss.getSheetByName('StockHistory')
    ```

### References:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Sheet: getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [Range: getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)
- [Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)
- [SpreadsheetApp: openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))
- [SpreadsheetApp: openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))
- [Spreadsheet: getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [Spreadsheet: getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So far, the code I've provided is the only function I have right now. Just to make sure as you said it is working fine with you, did it work when you called the function inside the sheet? or only from the Execution log?
The code is working just fine with me when I run it inside the apps script but when I try to call the function from within the sheet, I receive this error.

The issue still in the new spreadsheet as well

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if the new proposal works for you

Comment: Thank you. The problem with getActiveSheet in Spreadsheet Service is I'm trying to read from an inactive sheet (StockHistory), do some logic and then return the result to an active sheet (Test). So Spreadsheet Service will not work in my case.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how `Spreadsheet Service` can open inactive sheets